# What format is this date and how can I convert it to a regular datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis

Amazon for sellers provides order reports. I'm trying to import one of these order reports into a Sql Server database:

[image]

Their date fields look like this:

```
2014-04-30T12:17:28-07:00
2014-04-30T12:24:43-07:00
2014-04-30T12:25:34-07:00
2014-04-30T12:46:02-07:00
2014-07-27T13:10:02-07:00
2014-07-27T13:12:09-07:00
2014-07-27T13:20:42-07:00
2014-07-27T13:23:25-07:00
2014-07-27T13:29:10-07:00
2014-07-27T13:36:16-07:00
2014-07-27T13:51:41-07:00
```

I cannot figure out which data type to assign this date.

**How do I convert this field to be a regular datetime?** The solution could be SQL or SSIS or a combination.

Comment: That looks like a datetimeoffset to me. You can convert this is t-sql like this. select CAST('2014-04-30T12:17:28-07:00' as datetimeoffset)

Comment: @SeanLange thanks so much. what is a datetimeoffset and how does it convert to a datetime?

Comment: got it!@ thanks so much. please make that the answer

Comment: Do you care about adjusting the time according to the offset? The offset amount accounts for the timezone in relation to GMT. If you want to adjust to make the time consistent with your server time you will need use DATEADD to adjust the date appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.....

### SQL Server

```
SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME,
                  CONVERT(DATETIME2, '2014-04-30T12:17:28-07:00')
                  )

RESULT: 2014-04-30 12:17:28.000   --<-- SQL SERVER DATETIME
```

### SSIS

1. Convert your input column to SSIS Data type `DT_DBTIMESTAMP2`
2. Add a `derived column task` and use the following expression

   ```
   (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)Input_Column_Name
   ```

essentially you are doing the same thing but result will be the same.